# notify after event in followed node by follower

Tags: nodes, flags, notifications

I use the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module in Drupal 7, and created a flag (for nodes) with  "follow" as name of the flag.

I want to add new event on the followed content by user, send notify for follower by php code or display counter of new event unread to user.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you right, you want to do something after a user was flagged...

The flag module has a full [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module integration.
This module gives you the ability to react to specific events (like flagging a user) and do actions like showing a message, sending a email, or execute some custom php-code.